# Logic App - create table from CSV in email

Tags: azure, csv, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to send nice email with table (content from CSV file), similar here:
[Email test page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmKbP.png)

The biggest issue is formatting the table in email.
In Logic App in step "Send an Email" in Body is FILE CONTENT (here screenshot: [Logic App Send an Email screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5LZK.png). Table is not formatted and looks like:

```
test
SEP=, "NAME","SKU","TYPE","KIND","PLAN","TAGS","ALIASES","LOCATION","PROPERTIES","RESOURCE GROUP","SUBSCRIPTION","MANAGEDBY","IDENTITY","ZONES","TENANTID","APIVERSION" "VirtualMachine","null","microsoft.security/securitystatusessummaries","","null","null","{}","","{""resourceHealthSummryPerCategory"":[{""category"":""Compute"",""healthy"":null,""medium"":null,""high"":1,""none"":null,""low"":null},{""category"":""Networking"",""healthy"":null,""medium"":null,""high"":1,""none"":null,""low"":null}],""policyAssessmentsSummaries"":[{""policyDefinitionId"":null,""assessmentKey"":""12018f4f-3d10-999b-e4c4-86ec25be08a1"",""category"":""Compute"",""policyName"":""Virtual machines should be migrated to new Azure Resource Manager resources"",""healthy"":1,""medium"":null,""high"":null,""none"":null,""low"":null},{""policyDefinitionId"":null,""assessmentKey"":""3bcd234d-c9csdcs7-c2a2-89e0-c01f41dfv9c1a8a"",""category"":""Compute"",""policyName"":""Endpoint protection health issues should be resolved on your machines"",""healthy"":1,""medium"":null,""high"":null,""none"":null,""low"":null},{""policyDefinitionId"":null,""assessmentKey"":""8e2b96ff-3dedfvfd2-289b-b5c1-3b9921a34dfv41e"",""category"":""Compute"",""policyName"":""Monitoring agent health issues should be resolved on your machines"",""healthy"":1,""medium"":null,""high"":null,""none"":null,""low"":null},{""policyDefinitionId"":null,""assessmentKey"":""83f577bd-adfv1b6-b7e1-0891-12ca19d1dfve6df"",""category"":""Compute"",""policyName"":""Install endpoint protection solution on virtual machines"",""healthy"":1,""medium"":null,""high"":null,""none"":null,""low"":null},{""
```

I would like to get table instead ugly string.

Do you have any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below works ?

Comment: Yes. After some customisation, this works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requirement, I provide a sample below for your reference.

**1.** I upload a csv file to azure blob storage to simulate your situation.

[image]

**2.** Then search the action "Parse CSV" in you logic app.

[image]

**3.** It will ask you to input "API Key", you need to go to this [page](https://plumsail.com/documents/) first --> click "Start free trial", register an account and create a new API Key.
[image]
[image]
Copy the secret and paste it to your logic, it will allow you to connect Plumsail.

**4.** Input the "File Content" and the headers into the box, we can also add a new parameter "Skip first line" and set it "Yes"(this parameter will skip the header line and avoid two lines header in the expect table).
[image]

**5.** Now we need to use "[Create HTML table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#create-html-table-action)" action to create table by the data from "Parse CSV".
[image]

**6.** After that, we can send the email with the "Output" data from "Create HTML table" action.
[image]

**7.** The email I receive looks like below:

[image]